# Add a new element to the end of an existing cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

As the title already mentions, how is it possible to add a new cell array 1x1 at the end of an existing cell array, let's call him `Q`, which is a cell array 1x3256?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you mean adding a single cell to the end (i.e. so your *1*-by-*3256* cell array becomes a *1*-by-*3257* cell array) then:

```
Q{end+1} = []
```

and you can replace `[]` with your value directly

Alternatively:

```
Q(end+1) = {[]}
```

Comment: Man, that was quick... +1

Comment: Quick and useful reply! Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Adding to Dan's answer, in case you have a cell that is not a single dimension cell, you might want to add a full row, for example. In that case, access the cell as an array using `()`.

```
>> c = { 1, 'a'; 2, 'b'}

c = 

    [1]    'a'
    [2]    'b'

>> c(end+1,:) = {3,'c'}

c = 

    [1]    'a'
    [2]    'b'
    [3]    'c'
```